# The results viewer cannot execute a query with more than 655 columns in the project list

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sap-erp

I am using Visual Studio 2008's server explorer and I need to search through a database for invoice lines. So I find this one table named `ixvFact` but when I try to retrieve the results, visual studio gives me the following error and does not show me the results.

> The results viewer cannot execute a query with more than 655 columns in the project list.

What does this mean? How can I solve this?

Comment: It means that someone failed miserably as a DBA. Over 655 columns in one table? You gotta be kidding me...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Not much I can do about it, mate. I just have to deal with it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I've got one with over 1200 columns.  I tried desperately to get owner to let me create a relational schema for this feature, but he wanted it to look exactly like his other application that has over 3000 columns(split across 3 tables with no rhyme/reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify the columns you want to retrieve instead of selecting all columns from the table...I thought there was a limit on the number of columns in a table...that's very bad practices...

Comment: Is this a Visual Studio limitation then?

Comment: @DavideNguyen: Indeed, it is.

Comment: definitely, sql server should be able to hold 1000+ rows depending on data type (bytes) related to the objects in your schema

Comment: I suppose I will have to do this in separate queries to compare data then. Happy times on one's birthday. :)

Comment: yea - unfortunately - happy b-day bro :)

Comment: This limitation is in Management Studio too.  "DBA failures" aside, if SQL Server allows 1024 columns, then SSMS should be able to display them.