# Is it good approach for saving 800+ control properties in SQL Server table? Online Sharing Control Properties

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, properties

I searched many times about that. Actually maximum NO columns per SQL Server table is 1024. The problem is SQL Server prevents viewer if exceeded 655 (IDK why they do that...)

[image]

Some articles speak about that:

[Is there a hard limit as to how many columns can be returned in C# SqlDataAdapter Fill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977818/is-there-a-hard-limit-as-to-how-many-columns-can-be-returned-in-c-sharp-sqldataa)

[The results viewer cannot execute a query with more than 655 columns in the project list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773828/the-results-viewer-cannot-execute-a-query-with-more-than-655-columns-in-the-proj)

There's no actually solution or override a solution to make that acceptable after search...

Actually a properties that I need to save to columns Looks like:

```
TreeMenu_OptionsView_ShowColumns                           bit
TreeMenu_OptionsView_ShowColumns_Default                   bit
TreeMenu_OptionsView_ShowFilterPanelMode                   nvarchar(50)
TreeMenu_OptionsView_ShowFilterPanelMode_Default           nvarchar(50)
TreeMenu_OptionsView_ShowFirstLines                        bit  
TreeMenu_OptionsView_ShowFirstLines_Default                bit
++ more than 600 properties
```

Problem in my case (specially accessing control properties in clients PCs):

1. Saving properties in XML, json files is very good, but hard to modify it online. Only need to access each PC to apply new files for each PC.
2. Using file-based approach. Making other connected PC to SQL Server instance must have files. maybe duplication or something happened to files of PC3 or PC4.
3. Retrieving files in connected networks will not be fast as SQL Server `Select` query in any PC

I got solution which only will works at short-time term: separate a SQL Server table into 2 tables; one for control properties and one for control appearance

But after maybe months later new properties need to be added (40+ new options) so we will return to closed circle again...

If you have an opinion for that I will be very appreciated. Maybe there's something in SQL Server something maybe like caching tables (temp, etc) IDK

All I need is use SQL Server (alternate approaches are welcome).

At a glance: I need a solution to create something like cached table which columns can increased by the time

**Edited**

During problems of `sql_variant`, which is a low performance, and can't use `LIKE` statement with it. and values must inserted with a `CAST()` function to get a type we want. using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is better it can hold any kind of values.

see xanatos answer below for that.

Comment: I haven't ever seen using columns where the number of properties grows so much. It becomes easily unmanageable, as you've seen. If the properties are user-connected (perhaps their settings) a simple table like (UserId, Propertyname, ValueAsText) is probably better. If you want to be a little esoteric, sql supports the  `sql_variant` that can contains any value. If the properties are program-wide then (Propertyname, ValueAsText) is enough, or (Propertyname, ValueAsVariant)

Comment: You could just store JSON in an nvarchar(max) column. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 Or use XML if you prefer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Support%20for%20XML%20is%20integrated%20into%20all%20the,function%2C%20to%20retrieve%20XML%20data%20in%20relational%20format.

Comment: Hi David thanks for your answer! I would say JSON can saved as column and that's awesome. but any wrong character in JSON destroy whole properties. rather than destroy single column value, also *sql_variant* described below. Select a record from 1000 row is maybe slow than select single record with a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't ever seen using columns where the number of properties grows so much. It becomes easily unmanageable, as you've seen.

If the properties are user-connected (perhaps their settings) a simple table like

```
(UserId, PropertyName, ValueAsNVarChar)
```

is probably better.

If you want to be a little esoteric, SQL Server supports the  [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that can contains any value.

If the properties are program-wide then

```
(PropertyName, ValueAsNVarChar) is enough,
```

or

```
(PropertyName, ValueAsVariant)
```

It is a good idea to have another column with the expected .NET data type:

```
(PropertyName, ValueAsNVarChar, DotNetDataType) is enough,
```

Where `DotNetDataType` could be `System.Int32`, `System.Int64`, `System.String`, `System.Boolean`, `System.DateTime` and so on.

Comment: You really make me re-think about that. but *sql_variant* meaning Select a record from 1000 row is maybe slow than select single record with a column. much LINQ FirstOrDefault(), rather than `DataTable.Rows[0]["MyProperty"]` which accessing columns faster than search in LINQ, Also I see many guys say that sql_variant have many disadvantages. It can't modified directly from SQL-Server only from SQL Editor with Cast of type NVARCHAR, INT, etc. otherwise modify it directly from SQL Server Editor it will handled as NVARCHAR or string... I don't sure but I was tried that before.

Comment: Then save as an nvarchar(max) and be happy.

Comment: If you have same case what you will doing if have more than 1000+ properties with different type. and sql_variant has many cons. https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/problems-caused-by-use-of-the-sql_variant-datatype        What you will doing guide me as expertise person ;)

Comment: All those problems are for columns on which you want to do operations. You don't do operation on a value column. You don't SUM() them. The only problem is that the SQL Management Studio don't support them. You have to use SQL Man Studio, so sql_variant is a no-go. Go for the nvarchar(max) way, and add another column DotNetType, where you'll save the .NET data type expected (System.Int32, System.String, System.DateTime, System.Boolean ...)

Comment: @deveton Another option is to have a type column, a number of different nullable columns with different datatypes, and a check constraint allowing only one type. Consider using sparse columns for this

Comment: I think that Charlieface means like `(PropertyName, PropertyType, ValueAsInt, ValueAsDateTime, ValueAsString, ValueAsFloat, ValueAsDouble)` and so on, and every column has the data type based on the name

Comment: Yes xanatos, I see his approach also good one but many columns.. Did you will use his approach if you have same my problem? or PropertyType and NVARCHAR(MAX) one...

Comment: @deveton I would use my approach for a single reason. Before or later you'll have to save "complex" types in the property. You'll begin with comma-delimited values... perhaps a list of some american states that must be handled in a different way: AL;AZ;CO... And you'll say... It is a string... Then you'll need to save some additional information for each "special" state, and you'll decide to save the property as json or xml. So if you have a column for each "type", where should you put it? Should you add a new column? If you have only a nvarchar(max) column then there is no doubt. There :-)

Comment: Thank you xanatos, I will try that for sure. :)

Comment: @xanatos Really? You could just normalize that properly into further name/value pairs, perhaps with a parent reference. If you really want, you can always put JSON into `ValuesAsString`